# How do I get the attribute in an SWT Browser event?

Tags: javascript, java, macos, safari, swt

I create an instance of an SWT `Browser` and add a mouse listener to it. When the listener fires I want obtain the attribute of the element. I currently have this:

```
browser.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override 
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
        String SCRIPT = "var element=document.elementFromPoint(" + e.x + "," + e.y + ");" +
                        "return element.getAttribute('id');";
        String id = (String) browser.evaluate(SCRIPT);
    }
});
```

This works fine on Windows, but when I run it on a Mac (which I believe creates an instance of the Safari browser) getting wrong id,

Comment: You can't use `event` because it doesn't exist at the time of execution. You can pass the `x` and `y` coordinates of the `MouseEvent` to Javascript and then get the element based on the position though.

Comment: Hi Baz,Thank you for your answer and i updated my code as  browser.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
     @Override 
     public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
  String SCRIPT ="var element = document.elementFromPoint("+arg0.x+","+arg0.y+");return element.getAttribute('id');";
  String id=(String) browser.evaluate(SCRIPT);
     }
     });

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40744910/edit) and add the code there. And does it work now?

Comment: The above code is working fine in windows but giving null in Mac safari browser

Comment: can't really help you there, as I don't use safari.

Comment: Is there any alternate ways are there to get event attribute in MAC with SWT browser

Comment: Added a bit more back story to the question and made it clear that you're running code from an event handler for an SWT Browser - and that this is not a pure javascript question.